# TensorFlow strided_slice does not iterate backward over the entire range

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following test. I would like to reverse the rows with the last one being the first and so on.

```
    x_val = np.arange(3 * 2 * 3).astype(np.int64).reshape((3, 2, 3))
    print(x_val)
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, x_val.shape, name='input')
    x_ = tf.strided_slice(x, [3], [0], [-1])
    _ = tf.identity(x_, name='output')
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        variables_lib.global_variables_initializer().run()
        output_dict = []
        for out_name in ['output:0']:
            output_dict.append(sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name(out_name))
        expected = sess.run(output_dict, feed_dict={"input:0": x_val})
        print('test_strided_slice1', expected[0].shape, expected[0])
```

I am expecting my output to be:

```
[
  [
    [12. 13. 14.]
    [15. 16. 17.]
  ]
  [
    [ 6.  7.  8.]
    [ 9. 10. 11.]
  ]
  [
    [ 0  1  2]
    [ 3  4  5]
  ]
]
```

However I get:

```
[
  [
    [12. 13. 14.]
    [15. 16. 17.]
  ]
  [
    [ 6.  7.  8.]
    [ 9. 10. 11.]
  ]
]
```

As you can see the first row which is supposed to now be the last is missed.

If I step through like 0:3:1 I get all rows. But if I go in reverse I get one less.

Supplying no 'end' index causes the test to fail. Setting the 'end' to -1 also causes empty output.

Any suggestions on how to get this done?

Comment: Can you edit your code? I can't reproduce your result.

Comment: sorry about that. last minute desperate changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, it is more convenient to use [`tf.strided_slice`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strided_slice) through Python indexing syntax, so you could just do:

```
x_ = x[::-1]
```

However, it is possible to do what you want using [`tf.strided_slice`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strided_slice) directly. To do that, you need to use the `end_mask` parameter. In this integer value, if the i-th bit is set (starting from the least significant), then the corresponding `end` value for the i-th dimension is ignored and the slice is taken as far as possible. So you could do:

```
x_ = tf.strided_slice(x, [3], [0], [-1], end_mask=1)
```

Note I have changed the `4` in `begin` to `3`, since that is the actual index from where the slice starts (although it does work with `4` too). If you just want to take the slice going from the end to the beginning, you can also use `start_mask`, which works analogously to `end_mask`:

```
x_ = tf.strided_slice(x, [0], [0], [-1], start_mask=1, end_mask=1)
```

A small example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    x = tf.reshape(tf.range(18), [3, 2, 3])
    x_ = tf.strided_slice(x, [0], [0], [-1], start_mask=1, end_mask=1)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        print(sess.run(x_))
```

Output:

```
[[[12 13 14]
  [15 16 17]]

 [[ 6  7  8]
  [ 9 10 11]]

 [[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's what I was hoping to get.